# Showing download progress across multiple pages

Tags: objective-c

I have a project where a user can download up to three files simultaneously. I would like to show the progress of these downloads across multiple pages.

I am currently doing this through notifications like so...

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
      //do stuff here to calculate how much has been downloaded
      NSString* progress = ...
     //it would look like "3.4MB of 56MB"

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%@", video.videoID] object:progress];
 }];
```

So if I wanted to capture the progress for a particular video, I would just attach an observer on any page that would listen to the notification with the appropriate videoID.

Now this progress block gets called many many times when a file is being downloaded. To me, it just doesn't seem efficient to be posting notifications so rapidly. Though, the UI doesn't lag, and it works as it is suppose to.

Is there a better alternative that I'm missing? I wanted to be sure I wasn't doing anything...egregious

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing in apps before and never experienced problems. If you're concerned about the number of notifications, you could post a notification only every 5-10% of the download rather than on every update. But regardless, what you're doing should be fine.